# jQuery AJAX queue not getting response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, queue

I have an array has 100 item inside and each item should make an ajax request the problem is the server getting down of DDosAttack So I should make the requests in queue but I don't know why i'm getting response empty until all the requests is done.

```
array.map((row, index, arr)=> {
              return $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                async: false, // this caused the problem
                url: 'url',
                data: {...},
                success: function(data){  
                  console.log(data) //  appears only when all the requests is done
                },
                error: function(data){
                   console.log(data) //  appears only when all the requests is done
                }
              })

          })
```

Comment: The problem is because you're using `async: false`, so while all the AJAX requests occur one after the other, it completely blocks the browser from updating the UI while the requests are in progress. Sure, you can fix this in many ways, but regardless of any fixes, this is a highly flawed solution. Your problem of DDOS will still remain, just marginally harder to reach. To fix this properly, make a single request which gets *all* the required data instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wow thanks a bunch for this great explanation

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ajaxq` repository it's super helpful

https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ajaxq/downloads

```
array.map((row, index, arr)=> {
              return $.ajaxq('queue',{
                type: 'post',
                url: 'url',
                data: {...},
                success: function(data){  
                  console.log(data) //  appears only when all the requests is done
                },
                error: function(data){
                   console.log(data) //  appears only when all the requests is done
                }
              })

          })
```